# Time-weighted Pearson correlation

Tags: r, time-series, correlation, estimation, weights

I'm trying to calculate time-weighted Pearson correlation as described in https://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/FLAIRS/FLAIRS14/paper/viewFile/7817/7840    The coefficient is given by
$$
\rho_t(X,Y) = \left ( \frac{1-r}{1-r^N} \right ) \sum_{i=0}^{N} r^{i-1} \frac{(x_{-i} - \mu_X)(y_{-i} - \mu_Y)}{\sigma_X\sigma_Y},
$$
where $N+1$   is the number of observations,  $t=0,1,...,N$   indicates time period when the coefficient is calculated  ($t = N$ in my case, i.e. I'm calculating the correlation based on full sample),  $\sigma_X$, $\mu_X$, $x_{-i}$   denote standard deviation, expectation, and the   $i$th  latest observation in $X$  respectively, $r$  is the decay constant, equal to a real number less than 1.

My problem is that  $\rho_t(X,X) \neq 1$  when calculating it based on the formula above. Below is an example of how I calculate it in R.

```
set.seed(314)
N <- 1000
x <- cumsum(rnorm(N+1)) # random walk

cor(x, x) # Pearson correlation
# Result is 1

r <- 0.998
sigma <- sd(x)
mu <- mean(x)

(1 - r)/(1 - r^N) * sum( r^(0:N-1) * (x - mu)^2/sigma^2 ) # rho_t(x, x)
# Result is 1.171462
```

Please correct me if I have a bug in my code or suggest how I should modify the formula if it contains a mistake (my gut feeling says that the normalization might be wrong).

Comment: (+1) That paper's claims about the mathematical properties of $\rho_t$ are untrue.  If you would like a formula in which $\rho_t$ is assured of lying between $-1$ and $1$, *and actually equals those values* when there's perfect correlation, then you also need to compute weighted versions of  $\sigma_X$ and $\sigma_Y$ using the same weights.  (It hardly makes sense to use *unweighted* estimates of standard deviations for a *weighted* estimate of correlation in the first place.) You might even want to use weighted estimates of the means $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y$.

Comment: Please post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Answered in comments by whuber, copied here:

That paper's claims about the mathematical properties of $\rho_t$ are untrue. If you would like a formula in which $\rho_t$ is assured of lying between −1 and 1, and actually equals those values when there's perfect correlation, then you also need to compute weighted versions of $\sigma_X$ and $\sigma_Y$ using the same weights. (It hardly makes sense to use unweighted estimates of standard deviations for a weighted estimate of correlation in the first place.) You might even want to use weighted estimates of the means $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y$.